# how to update certain parts of text file in java

Tags: java, text-files, bufferedreader

I want to be able to update a certain line on a text file.
But I get the error that it cannot delete the file, why do I get this error?

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main rlf = new Main();
        rlf.removeLineFromFile("F:\\text.txt", "bbb");
    }

    public void removeLineFromFile(String file, String lineToRemove) {
        try {
            File inFile = new File(file);

            if (!inFile.isFile()) {
                System.out.println("Parameter is not an existing file");
                return;
            }

            //Construct the new file that will later be renamed to the original filename.
            File tempFile = new File(inFile.getAbsolutePath() + ".tmp");

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));

            String line = null;

            //Read from the original file and write to the new
            //unless content matches data to be removed.
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                if (!line.trim().equals(lineToRemove)) {

                    pw.println(line);
                    pw.flush();
                }
            }
            pw.close();
            br.close();

            //Delete the original file
            if (!inFile.delete()) {
                System.out.println("Could not delete file");
                return;
            }

            //Rename the new file to the filename the original file had.
            if (!tempFile.renameTo(inFile)) System.out.println("Could not rename file");

        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}​
```

Comment: Do you have write access to the F drive?

Comment: Can you delete the file if you close it first?

Comment: Which line is the exception happening on?

Comment: yes, I'm logged in as admin. The file is closed when I run it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program works for me.  Perhaps you are having an environmental issue.

Comment: do I need to put it on the same directory,

Comment: Why the down vote?  The program, as written, works for me.  @user225269 I don't think so.

Answer (score 2):

You should look into [`RandomAccessFile`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html).

This will let you seek to the place in the file you want, and only update the part that you want to update.

Comment: This is the approach you would want to use

Answer (score 0):

As Justin pointed out above, you should be using the RandomAccessFile kind of api if you want to modify parts of file. The approach you are trying to use has a lot of potential problems.

- It requires a tmp file to be created in addition. May not scale for large files (I am not aware of your problem domain, though)
- Trying to juggle files also can cause several potential exceptions, and requires lots of error handling.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new instance (to close the old) by `new` then delete using it.
Same file delete problem  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/991489/i-cant-delete-a-file-in-java)