# How to check if a file can be deleted?

Tags: java, io

How can I **check** that I can delete a file in Java?

For example, if a file `test.txt` is opened in another program I can't delete it. And I have to know it before actual deletion, so I can't do this:

```
if (!file.delete()) { ... }
```

And `srcFile.canWrite()` is not working either.

Comment: what happens when you use try/catch blocks?

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/991489/i-cant-delete-a-file-in-java

Comment: Thanks, but questions not about deleting but knowing that file in use by another proccess now, so it actually should not be deleted..

Comment: Generally speaking that's a question that you won't get a good answer to in most OS: there may be many factors that determine if you can delete a file or not and the only sure-fire way to check is to try it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the file with a Write Lock.

See here http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileLock.html

```
FileChannel channel = new RandomAccessFile("C:\\foo", "rw").getChannel();

// Try acquiring the lock without blocking. This method returns
// null or throws an exception if the file is already locked.
FileLock lock = channel.tryLock();

// ...  

// release it
lock.release();
```

Comment: That's only a partial solution: it's possible to get write access to a file and still not be allowed to delete it.

Comment: thanks, it works. But I had to call channel.close() after lock.release() to be able delete a file, because file was locked by FileChannel.

Comment: I found situation where that's not working - as Joachim Sauer said. So do you know any final solution to this ?

Comment: actually I found this working for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13048956/1829381

Answer (score 5):

On my Windows 7 64 bit box using NTFS and Java 7, the only thing which worked for me reliably is

```
boolean canDelete = file.renameTo(file)
```

This is surprisingly simple and works also for folders, which have "somewhere below" an "open" or "locked" file.

Other things I tried and produced false-positives: aquire a FileLock, File#canWrite, File#setLastModified ("touch")

Answer (score 3):

Under Unix, you need write permission to the parent directory in order to delete a file.

Under Windows, permissions can be a lot more fine-grained, but write-access to the directory would catch most cases there as well, I believe. In addidtion, you should try and aqquire a write-lock on the file when under windows.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into [FileLock](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileLock.html). There is a [FileChannel.tryLock()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#tryLock%28%29) method that will return null if you cannot obtain a lock.