# How to check if I can delete a file?

Tags: java, file, io, delete-file

How can I **check** that I can delete a file in Java?

For example, I **should** be able to delete file `C:/file.txt` but I **never** will be able to delete the `C:/` or `Computer`, or `My Documents` etc.

Solution described in [possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5078121/2123487) does not work for me.

Comment: *"Solution described in possible duplicate does not works for me."* Please explain why?

Comment: @Marco Forberg Sometimes it throws an `Access is denied` exception for usual files such as `C:/file.txt`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Removing file requires write permission of the file's parent, i.e. directory where file is stored. Directory in java is also represented by instance of class `java.io.File` that has method `canWrite()`.

So, to check whether file can be deleted you should call `file.getParent().canWrite()`.

Comment: +1 excellent solution but it's actually `file.getParentFile().canWrite()`.

Comment: This is unreliable.  For example, on a POSIX system you can write to a directory with the [restricted deletion bit](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chmod.1.html#RESTRICTED_DELETION_FLAG_OR_STICKY_BIT) set but you can not delete any file you don't own.  It's also a [TOCTOU bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-check_to_time-of-use).  If you need to delete a file, **DELETE THE FILE**.

Answer (score 6):

On my Windows 7 64 bit box using NTFS and Java 7 (Oracle JDK), the only thing which worked for me reliably is

```
boolean canDelete = file.renameTo(file)
```

This is surprisingly simple and works also for folders, which have "somewhere below" an "open" or "locked" file.

Other things I tried and produced false-positives: aquire a FileLock, File#canWrite, File#setLastModified ("touch"), file.getParent().canWrite()

Comment: It should be noted that the behavior of this function is platform-dependant.

Answer (score 0):

Addition to the `AlexR` answer.

If you are using `Path` and Java `nio`, I would suggest using something like the following:

```java
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;

boolean canDelete = Files.isWritable(file.getParent())
```