# Grails/Groovy file deletion

Tags: java, file, grails, groovy, delete-file

I am having a tough time deleting a file.  I will show you what is working, and you can be the judge if this is acceptable.

```
class StupidService{
def doThings(){
  def tmpDirString = "dumpit"
  def currentDir = new File("../${tempDirString}")
  currentDir.eachFile(FileType.FILES){
    def f=it
    def answer = SuperComplicatedService.doStuff(f)
    //this works, now I need to move the file to the "done" folder
    File dir = new File("../${tempDirString}/done");  
    def endupFile = new File("../${tempDirString}/done/${f.name}")
    FileUtils.copyFile(f, endupFile)
    //this works; the file is copied to where I want it successfully; now I just need to delete the initial file.
    def thisIsAJoke=0
    while(f.delete()==false){
      println "This is not a joke: ${thisIsAJoke}"
      thisIsAJoke++
    }

  }
}
}
```

And so this prints out between 40k and 150k lines of "This is not a joke: 64457" etc. and then finally deletes the file.

What is going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What does `SuperComplicatedService.doStuff(f)` do? If it opens the file, make sure it closes it before returning. Otherwise, you won't be able to delete the file until the garbage collector collects the object that references it.

See [I can't delete a file in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/991489/i-cant-delete-a-file-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

> Code for delete a file and folder of the file in Groovy/Grails

```
    String filePath = "c:/dir"+"/"+"carpeta"+"/"+documentoInstance.nombreArchivo
    String folderPath = "c:/dir"+"/"+"carpeta"+"/"
    boolean fileSuccessfullyDeleted =  new File(filePath).delete()
    boolean folderSuccessDeleted = new File(folderPath).deleteDir()
    if(fileSuccessfullyDeleted && folderSuccessDeleted){
        documentoInstance.delete flush:true
    }
    else{
        flash.error = "Archivo no borrado."
        return
    }
```