# Java 6 File Deletion

Tags: java, file, io, java-6

I am aware that this question is a raging duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/991489/i-cant-delete-a-file-in-java) question. **However**, I have now read that entire page twice, and some sections 3 times, and for the life of me I don't see how/where it is answered!

So, on to my problem.

I am at work and am stuck using Java 6 SE and cannot upgrade to 7. I am writing a program that creates a file, writes to it, does some processing, and then needs to delete the file out of existence. I am having the exact same problem as the person who asked the question I reference above: Java will not delete the file and I cannot figure out why.

The code:

```
File f = null;
FileWriter fw = null;
try
{
    f = new File("myFile.txt");
    fw = new FileWriter(f);
    fw.write("This is a sentence that should appear in the file.");
    fw.flush();
    if(f.delete())
        System.out.println("File was successfully deleted.");
    else
        System.err.println("File was not deleted.");
}
catch(Exception exc)
{
    System.err.println(exc.getMessage());
}
catch(Error er    {
    System.err.println(er.getMessage());
}
catch(Throwable t)
{
    System.err.println(t.getMessage());
}
finally
{
    fw.close();
}
```

It is not throwing any throwables, errors or exceptions (I included those to rule out *any* and all edge cases). The second print statement (`"File was not deleted."`) is being printed to the console. I am running this on Windows 7 and am writing to a folder where I have full permissions (rwx).

The user asking the question I referenced answered his own question, but does so (in my humble opinion) in a not-so-straight-forward way. In any case, I am having trouble making sense of it. He/she seems to be alluding to the fact that using a `BufferedReader` as opposed to a `FileInputStream` made the difference for him/her, but I just don't see how that applies.

Java 7 seems to have fixed this issues with the introduction of a `java.nio.file.Files` class, but again, I can't use Java 7 for reasons outside the scope of my control.

Other answerers to that referenced question allude that this is a "bug" in Java, and give all sorts of circumventions, such as explicitly calling `System.gc()`, etc. I have tried all of these and they are not working.

Maybe someone can add a fresh perspective and jog some thinking for me.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate.  As you have tried the suggested solutions from the other question and they did not help, it is likely that the cause is different.

Comment: Close it first. And... "stuck using Java 6?" I don't know a single corporation that's running on JDK7. I know many that are on 1.4 and 1.5. Consider yourself lucky.

Comment: please note what you said is opposite: using FileInputStream instead of BufferedReader is what worked for the user in the other post. As for why it applies, some comment there suggests its a bug in Java.

Comment: Question for the folks who also experience this problem -- what OS/version and HD are you using? We've been experiencing this issue up the wazzo on Win7 64bit dev workstations with Intel X-25M SSDs. However, I don't believe our linux deployment boxes see the issue.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You're trying to delete() a file which is still referenced by an active, open FileWriter.

Try this:

```
f = new File("myFile.txt");
fw = new FileWriter(f);
fw.write("This is a sentence that should appear in the file.");
fw.flush();
fw.close(); // actually free any underlying file handles.
if(f.delete())
    System.out.println("File was successfully deleted.");
else
    System.err.println("File was not deleted.");
```

Answer (score 8):

You can only delete the file if there is no file handler left opened. Since you open the file hanlder using `FileWriter`, you will need to close it before you can delete it. In other word, `f.delete` must be executed after `fw.close`

Try the code below. I made the changes to prevent all possible bug you may found, e.g if fw is null.

```
File f = null;
FileWriter fw = null;
try {
    f = new File("myFile.txt");
    fw = new FileWriter(f);
    fw.write("This is a sentence that should appear in the file.");
    fw.flush(); // flush is not needed if this is all your code does. you data
                // is automatically flushed when you close fw
} catch (Exception exc) {
    System.err.println(exc.getMessage());
} finally {// finally block is always executed.
    // fw may be null if an exception is raised in the construction 
    if (fw != null) {
        fw.close();
    }
    // checking if f is null is unneccessary. it is never be null.
    if (f.delete()) {
        System.out.println("File was successfully deleted.");
    } else {
        System.err.println("File was not deleted.");
    }
}
```