# Cannot delete directory with image

Tags: java, directory

I am trying to delete the content of the directory with few files, and I am not able to delete it. When I tried the methods `.delete()` it returns a `false`, but `.canWrite()`, `.canRead()` method returns `true` for the code.

My file path in the system is:

E:\PROJECT01022012\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp4\wtpwebapps\realmap\PHOTO\VFIN5CT5651842012\Inspirational-GravityHighRes.jpg

I tried [this](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0180__File/Removeadirectoryandallofitscontents.htm)  and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/991489/i-cant-delete-a-file-in-java) but no luck.

```
public static boolean removeDirectory(File directory){

 if (directory.isDirectory())
    {
     File[] fls=directory.listFiles();

     for (int i = 0; i < fls.length; i++) {
          fls[i].delete();

     }
     } 

}
```

Comment: The java2s approach should work: you cannot delete a non-empty directory - you have to delete all its contents (recursively) first. Are you sure your directory is not read-only?

Comment: yes i have mentioned it .canWrite() method returns a true value.

Comment: Did you try to debug the code ? What is 'fls[i].delete' returning ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot delete a file if it's already been opened elsewhere. E.g. in Java by an `FileInputStream` or `FileOutputStream` which isn't been closed, or outside Java's context in enduser's image viewer/editor or so.

In Java side, make sure that you aren't opening the file anywhere. Make sure that any `FileInputStream` and `FileOutputStream` on that file is been `close()`d in `finally` block after use. Make sure that the enduser itself isn't opening the picture in some image viewer/editor.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your files in directory is read only? If yes, you can try setReadOnly(false) - but I remember that does not work. It is actually does not reset read only flag from file. Well, some work around can be call of Runtime.exec with command to delete your files for your OS:

```
// For windows - option /F to force delete read-only files:
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("DEL /F E:\PROJECT01022012\.metadata\.plugins" +
    "\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp4\wtpwebapps\realmap\PHOTO\VFIN5CT5651842012" +
    "\Inspirational-GravityHighRes.jpg");
```