# File#delete not deleting files

Tags: java, io

I need to delete a directory containing some files. I am using the following code:

```
public static void delete(File f) {
  if (f.isDirectory()) {
    for (File c : f.listFiles()) {
      delete(c);
    }
  }
  f.setWritable(true);
  f.delete();
}
```

For some reason, some files inside the directory, and hence the directory does not get deleted. What could be the possible reasons for this behavior, and how can I solve this problem?

Comment: They could be used and locked by another process, or yours. Or you may simply not have the rights.

Comment: I invoked `System.gc()` as suggested in [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/991489/i-cant-delete-a-file-in-java), and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that the file is open somewhere, assuming you have write permisions to the directory.  Trying to delete a file which hasn't been properly closed is a common source of strange failures to delete.  After the program exists you find that the file can be deleted.

Comment: The file in question isn't likely open. Its grand-grand-parent is. But I don't know if that should be a problem.

Comment: I invoked `System.gc()` as suggested in [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/991489/i-cant-delete-a-file-in-java), and it worked.

Comment: This means there are some files which have been discarded without being closed. The solution is to make sure that a file is always closed in a `finally` block so it is even closed if an exception is thrown. Or use Java 7's ARM.

Comment: but no exceptions are being thrown.

Comment: In that case they are simply being discarded.

Comment: Okay. Is calling `System.gc` a bad idea in this case?