# Java Sound API locks audio file after playing it

Tags: java, audio, javasound

I am trying to use Javax.sound to play a .wav file.
Everything works fine, the file plays as expected and in the end I close the Clip and I close the AudioInputStream. However, the file remains locked (in use) after that and I cannot touch it without getting an exception:  java.nio.file.FileSystemException: alerting.wav: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

A sample of code is below:

```
static private class SoundThread extends Thread implements LineListener {
    private boolean playCompleted;
    private int cycles;
    
    public SoundThread(int repeats) {
        cycles = repeats;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Clip clip;
        AudioInputStream inputStream;
        File soundFile = new File("alerting.wav");
        try {
            inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundFile);
            try {
                clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
                clip.addLineListener(this);
                clip.open(inputStream);
                while(cycles > 0) {
                    playCompleted = false;
                    clip.setFramePosition(0);
                    clip.start();
                    while(!playCompleted) {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    }
                    Thread.sleep(audioRepeatTime * 1000);
                    cycles--;
                }
                //clip.drain();
                clip.close();
                inputStream.close();
                System.out.println("All closed");
                try {
                    this.finalize();
                } catch (Throwable ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Main.syslog(Level.WARNING, "E1001 could not play alert sound", ex);
            } finally {
                inputStream.close();
            }
        } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException ex) {
            Main.syslog(Level.WARNING, "E1001 could not play alert sound", ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Main.syslog(Level.WARNING, "E1001 could not play alert sound", ex);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void update(LineEvent event) {
        LineEvent.Type type = event.getType();
        
        System.out.println("Event: " + type);
        if(type == LineEvent.Type.STOP) {
            playCompleted = true;
        } else if (type == LineEvent.Type.CLOSE) {
            System.out.println("listener closed");
        }
    }
}

public static void PlayAlertSound() {
    if(enableAudio) {
        SoundThread st = new SoundThread(audioLoops);
        st.start();
    }
} 

public static void PlayAlertSound(int repeats) {
    if(enableAudio) {
        SoundThread st = new SoundThread(repeats);
        st.start();
    }
}
```

In the Java threads list I see "Java Sound Event Dispatcher" running. I think this is what keeps the file locked.
Any idea how can I fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The API for Clip states:

> Note that some lines, once closed, cannot be reopened. Attempts to
> reopen such a line will always result in a `LineUnavailableException`.

I'm going to make a couple additional suggestions.

Instead of using `File`, a better way to load audio resources is with the `class.getResource` method. This method returns a `URL` which you can then pass as your argument to the `AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream` method.

I'm not clear what you are trying to do, but I also recommend some further changes to your code. Initializing and playing a `Clip` in the same method is not generally done, as it goes against the intended use of the `Clip`. A `Clip` is meant for sounds that can be held in memory. So, make your `Clip` an instance variable. Then, place the code that loads and opens the `Clip` in its own method.  And put the code that calls `start` or `loop` in a separate method or methods, and don't close the `Clip` at the end of playing unless you are sure you are not going to ever play it again.

If you use `clip.loop`, you don't have to bother with listeners and count iterations.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't have any problems with playing sound, that works fine. My problem is that when I don't play the sound and everything is closed, the file is still locked by the system and cannot be modified or deleted. I just want to be able, in some other dialog window, to load a different .wav form computer and save it with same name as initial file. It looks like AudioInputStream still locks the file although I closed it.
I also tried to use Media and MediaPlayer but same thing happens.

Comment: Maybe the File command is holding on. Try using URL instead. I just noticed you are doing everything within a "sound thread". It's rarely needed to handle sounds--new threads are launched every time a sound is played. Sorry I can't help more but the way you are doing things is confusing to me. I think simplifying would go a long way to solving your issue. Maybe try just making a simple Clip, call it, play it, let it get garbage-collected, and then see if you can load the file. I know I've loaded files wav files multiple times in the past, but always with their own AudioInputStreams.

Comment: This is a part of very complex program, it is not a sound player. This is why I am using a thread. The program has to run and doing its job and sometimes it has to play a sound for a programmed number of times at some configurable intervals without holding the whole program. However, I tried just to play sound without thread only once. Once the file was played, it becomes "in use by other process" and cannot be touched anymore.
Thanks

Comment: This is same as this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11316289/cannot-delete-file-even-after-closing-audioinputstream which never got a right answer

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
//...
AudioInputStream inputStream;
File soundFile = new File("alerting.wav");
try {
    inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundFile);
    // ...
}
// ...
```

Try this:

```
//...
AudioInputStream inputStream;
File soundFile = new File("alerting.wav");
try {
    byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(soundFile.toPath());
    inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
    // ...
}
// ...
```