# Force Delete all files from a folder

Tags: java, file-io, delete-file, fileinputstream

I have been using a specific piece of code to delete files from a folder but it is proving very problematic because maybe I forgot to close an InputStream or two. The code I have is so big that I am not be able to see all the Inputstreams that I have not closed. Is there a way of deleting files whether there is an open InputStream or not?

This is the piece of the code that I have been using;

```
File fin = new File("C:/ABC Statements final/");
    File[] finlist = fin.listFiles();       
    for (int n = 0; n < finlist.length; n++) {
        if (finlist[n].isFile()) {
        System.gc();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
            finlist[n].delete();
        }
    }
```

I have edited the code. This version works.

Comment: I'd suggest that the short answer is no.  You should be taking care of you streams better.

Comment: Then I should say that I have gone through Every Inpustream There is in the code and I have closed the whole lot of them But I still got the same error

Comment: 2 thoughts.  Some one, some where is holding a file open &/or there is a permissions issue

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There is no InputStream instances in the provided chunk of code.

To not write lots of untested IO code, please take a look at the [apache.commons.io](http://commons.apache.org/io/) project. Especially at the [FileDeleteStrategy](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileDeleteStrategy.html) class, for file deletion operations.

Your code might look like that:

```
File fin = new File("C:/ABC Statements final/");

for (File file : fin.listFiles()) {
    FileDeleteStrategy.FORCE.delete(file);
}
```

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Unable to delete file: C:\ABC Statements final\Statement0.RPT
 at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.forceDelete(FileUtils.java:1390)
 at org.apache.commons.io.FileDeleteStrategy$ForceFileDeleteStrategy.doDelete(FileDeleteStrategy.java:151)
 at org.apache.commons.io.FileDeleteStrategy.delete(FileDeleteStrategy.java:94)
 at abcbankestatement.ABCBankEStatement.main(ABCBankEStatement.java:502)
Java Result: 1

Comment: if you replace the `delete` method with `deleteQuietly` one. In this case **if a file could not be deleted, no exception will be thrown**.

Comment: It is not the Exceptions I want to get rid of, I need the files deleted.

Comment: please read this thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/991489/i-cant-delete-a-file-in-java

Comment: Actually, That's Windows, baby!

Comment: Actually From the Link you Shared Above, I found the Answer to My Problem. I have added the bit `System.gc()` and the bit `Thread.sleep` and the files are getting deleted. Thank you Man.

Answer (score 5):

You can use:

```
FileUtils.deleteDirectory(File directory)
```

from [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html)

Comment: Probably better to use `cleanDirectory()` since it says it doesn't delete the directory. However, I'm not 100% sure what "clean" means. I *assume* it means it deletes the directory contents, but the documentation is *awful*, so I can't be certain.

Answer (score 3):

With Apache Commons IO:

```
File dir = ...
FileUtils.deleteQuietly(dir);
dir.mkdirs();
```

No need to check for exceptions this way.

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
   import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
   FileUtils.cleanDirectory(fin);
```

Docs:

```
 /**
     * Clean a directory without deleting it.
     *
     * @param directory directory to clean
     * @throws IOException in case cleaning is unsuccessful
     */
```

In order to use it you need a dependency:

**Maven:**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
</dependency>
```

**Gradle:**

```
compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.6'
```

Comment: Sometimes libraries are life saver. Java is very good language but unfortunately it is making something difficult.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void removeDir()
{
try
{
    File dir = new File((System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/ReportFolderToMail"+timeStamp));
    if (dir.isDirectory())
    {
        File[] files = dir.listFiles();
        if (files != null && files.length > 0)
        {
            for (File aFile : files) 
            {
                System.gc();
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                 FileDeleteStrategy.FORCE.delete(aFile);
                System.out.println("delet file" +aFile);
            }
        }
        dir.delete();
        System.out.println("delet" +dir);
    } 
    else 
    {
        dir.delete();
    }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Please add some documentation/explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean removeDir()
{
try
{
   //destFile = new File((System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/FileName"))
   // checks if the directory has any file
    File dir = destFile; 
    if (dir.isDirectory())
    {
        File[] files = dir.listFiles();
        if (files != null && files.length > 0)
        {
            for (File aFile : files) 
            {
                System.gc();
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                FileDeleteStrategy.FORCE.delete(aFile);
                System.out.println("delet file" +aFile);
            }
        }
        dir.delete();
        System.out.println("delet" +dir);
    } 
    else 
    {
        dir.delete();
    }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    logger.log(LogStatus.FATAL, "Exception Occured While Deleting Folder : " +e);
}
return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**I simply did this and it worked awesomely:**

```
            System.gc();
            //then
            Files.delete(chosenFile.toPath());
            FileDeleteStrategy.FORCE.delete(chosenFile);
```