# Can't delete file in JAVA

Tags: java, delete-file

I can't delete a file in Java. In my program, I create a file, do something with it, and then I have to delete it. When I call myFile.delete(), it returns false. I have checked the path it is trying to delete and its correct, I also have administrator privileges (I'm working on Windows 7). Here is my piece of code, very simple:

```
File aux = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"//tmp.ps");

CreatePostScript(aux.getAbsoluteFilePath());
SendToPrinter();

try{
    aux.delete();
}
catch(SecurityException ex){
     ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Edit, I have read some properties of the File object:

```
canRead() returns false
canWrite() returns false
exists() returns false
getPath() returns the_actual_path_of_the_file
isFile() returns false
```

Comment: what is the exception your are getting

Comment: He gets no exception, `delete()` returns false.

Comment: possiblity duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/991489/668970

Comment: think you must use `user.home` instead of `user.dir`

Comment: Make sure the file exists and isn't opened by a program.

Comment: So your file does not exist, but ``delete`` returns ``false``.
Can you check whether it ``exists`` before you call ``delete``?

Comment: exists() returns false before and after delete(). But the file exists, I can see it

Comment: In that case, please see @ice's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Are you doing that from inside some IDE? Probably the IDE is holding file handle. 
Try to download [Unlocker](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/) and to see who is holding the handle.

Comment: Unlocker says no program is locking the file

Comment: Try to delete the file with Unlocker. If it can be deleted , then definitely something (very probably NetBeans)is  holding the handle. Also try to rename the file and then to delete it. If it works, then, again, something (very probably NetBeans)is  holding the file handle.

Answer (score 1):

As you are performing processing on the file it is likely that an `OutputStream` is still open. Call `out.close();` before attempting to delete the file.

Comment: What stream? I just create the File and use its path to execute a command with Runtime.getRuntime().exec

Comment: Ok, does the file exist before you attempt to delete it?

Answer (score 1):

Check that you provide `user.dir` property thought `-D` command-line argument. 
And use [File.pathSeparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#pathSeparator) instead of `//`

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I think that is not the problem, the filepath that the getPath() function returns is correct.

Comment: Why you add `//` before file name? In windows file separator is `\\\`.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using Java 7's [NIO2 API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html) for the operation. Instead of returning a success value, it actually [throws an exception](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileOps.html#exception) when something stops it from performing an operation.

Comment: I've used Unlocker as suggested in another answer and the file is not locked.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice that one. Removed that part of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

in your code, i see you are not closing the stream before you are deleting, close the stream and delete the file.

Comment: What stream? I just create the File and use its path to execute a command with Runtime.getRuntime().exec

Comment: you are calling methods after file creation, what does those methods do,

Comment: The CreatePostScript() method does call the exec() function passing the filepath as an argument. The method itself don't do any work with the file, I use the File class to work with filepaths

Comment: if it doesnot do any thing with that file, whay are you passing it to the method?

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake, it actually is CreatePostScript(aux.getAbsolutePath()). Again, sorry

Comment: please clarify, are you closing that exec() call properly. i feel, they may stops in deleting the file, please provide more details about that method

Comment: I think the problem is the exec() call. It calls a .exe to create a PostScript file, but the delete() call is just after exec(), so it doesn't wait until the .exe finishes it's work.

Comment: that what i said in previous comment, check with that call