# Java I/O. delete() method not deleting created file from directory

Tags: java, io, mkdir

This code creates a .txt in the folder directory (it works) but when comes the time to delete the whole directory or the .txt file using `delete()` method,  nothing happens.
The `delete()` method works only when I replace the .txt file with an ordinary folder

```
import java.io.*;

public class Filemkdir {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
                File f = new File("C:/Temp/Java/secret.txt");


                FileWriter fSecret = new FileWriter(f);
                f.mkdir();

                f.delete();
        }
}
```

Comment: Similar discussion you can check it [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/991489/i-cant-delete-a-file-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the fSecret (`FileWriter`) needs to be closed first. Otherwise the file is "in use"

```
fSecret.close();
```

Answer (score 5):

On Windows you can't delete an open file. Close the `FileWriter` first.

Also, the

```
f.mkdir();
```

seems completely pointless.

Answer (score 1):

You would basically need to close the writer object before deleting the file

Answer (score 0):

File delete work on file, if you are trying to delete directory you first need to delete all files inside id.

with your code you are giving path for file, but you are creating directory after that.