# setReadOnly() vs canWrite()

Tags: java, file, delete-file

I'm trying to delete a file but no matter what I try it doesn't seem to work. I set the file to read only using `setReadOnly()` and then immediately check to see if I can write to it and I can. I'm using windows and I have found that there could be bugs with these methods. Is there any way to completely close a file and cut off all access to make sure I can delete it?

Comment: Where the file is coming from? Are you generating it in your code? If so please provide the code.

Comment: Maybe look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/991489/i-cant-delete-a-file-in-java