# JSP output to IFrame

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets, iframe

I have posted another relative question: [Java Servlet: delete temporary file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17877118)

As per the suggestion of @BalusC, I have been trying to implement something different, but to no success.

Therefore, I want to ask the following: is it possible to "inject" HTML contents into an iframe at runtime?

Just to clarify, I am working with Servlets and JSP. I have one servlet which on `doPost` populates and displays a JSP page. The page is as follows:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>

<script> function disp() {
  alert(document.getElementById('ifrm').contentDocument.documentElement.innerHTML); } 
</script>    

<style type="text/css">
  html, body, div { margin:0; padding:0; height:100%; }
  iframe { display:block; width:100%; height:90%; border:none; }
</style>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>This is SPARTA!!</title>
</head>

<body>
  <a href='getter?url=<%= request.getRequestURI() %>&starter=fine'>Close Session</a>
  <input type='button' onclick='disp()' value='Source'></input>
  You want me to load: <%= request.getParameter("url") %> , and here it is:

  <iframe id='ifrm' src='<%= request.getSession().getAttribute("relpath") %>'></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

"relpath" is an attribute I add to the session at a previous point, and represents a relative path to a temporary file. It works, but I have an ulterior problem: the links in the page contained inside the iframe are appropriately changed so that they function properly. The effect is that one can navigate inside the iframe as if it were a browser tab. So, when a link on the page is clicked, the temporary file gets re-written with the contents of the site the link points to. However, the page is not reloaded, and I gather it is because the browser retrives the cached page, and not the page from the browser. I tried refreshing the source of the iframe via JavaScipt and it functions, but there is delay, and the page loads twice - I don't want that. I have also tried doind it with `document.write()` in JavaScript on the iframe object, again with no success.

A last clarification: the iframe should contain the whole HTML of the page, complete with the `<html>` and `</html>` tags: I did think of creating a JSP page with a DIV perhaps, and injecting the content there, but that's not what I want either...

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I actually managed to resolve the issue by myself.

In the end, I came back to JavaScript. Using Beans, I managed to pass the contents of the page to the JSP page, and there I simply "echo" the lines of the document one by one. I have to advise anyone who is interested that I encountered some difficulties with escaping special characters: I had to manually escape CR and LF in some cases, and had to handle existing `</script>` tags in the page, as they cause the JavaScript to exit prematurely. I managed to overcome this difficulty by changing the character `'<'` to `\x3C`, as has been suggested on another thread here, on SO.