# Can not delete file in java beause it's opened in Java Platform SE binary

Tags: java

I have three directories A, B & C on windows. I have a file that exists in directory A.  I want to do the following tasks

1. Copy it to directory B
2. Delete it from directory A (This WORKED since the file was not being held by any process)
3. Copy it to directory C
4. Delete it from directory B (NOT Work)

Steps 1,2,3 work fine but it does not work with step 4.  The file exists and can write, read, execute.  When I open windows explorer and try to delete the file in directory B manually, it said the action can't be completed because it's opened in java platform SE binary.  Below is my code for copying the file

```
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(source);
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dest);

        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int len;

        while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
            out.write(buf, 0, len);
        }

        in.close();
        out.close();
```

I'm using Java 6. Do you know how I can accomplish step 4?

Comment: What's the point of copying it to directory B if you just delete it in the last step?

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/991489/i-cant-delete-a-file-in-java

Comment: If A, B, and C are all in the same file system, why not use a rename instead of one of the copy steps?

Comment: I have to do something with the file so I have to copy it to directory B.  I tried rename before and it did not work either.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a library like Apache Commons IO (FileUtils)?

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html

```
File a = new File("A/file.txt");
File b = new File("B/file.txt");
File c = new File("C/file.txt");
FileUtils.copyFile(a, b);
a.delete();
FileUtils.copyFile(b, c);
b.delete();
```

Comment: I still can't delete b because Java SE is still holding on to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

> Code

```
       public void foo(){
        File afile =new File("A\\Afile.txt");
        File bfile =new File("B\\Bfile.txt");
        InputStream  inStream = new FileInputStream(afile);
        OutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(bfile);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        int length;
        //copy the file content in bytes 
        while ((length = inStream.read(buffer)) > 0){

            outStream.write(buffer, 0, length);

        }

        inStream.close();
        outStream.close();

        System.out.println("File Copied");
        if(afile.delete()){
            System.out.println(file.getName() + " deleted!");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Delete failed.");
        }
      }
```

Please make sure you use proper try and catch clauses

Comment: I still can't delete aFile since it's being held by Java SE binary process

Answer (score -1):

If you know how to open **Windows Task Manager** then open that and click **Processes** then you click the word **DESCRIPTION** at the top then scroll and look for the word **JAVA** then you right click it and click **End Process Tree** once you have gone through that then you close **Windows Task Manager** and go back to **File Explorer** then you go back to the **Java** file and delete it or open it to delete whatever you want to delete in the file i hope this helps with your problem