# java delete file from folder

Tags: java, file

I am trying to delete a file:
This is the code and I can't see anything wrong

```
System.out.println("users//"+"user"+i.getId());
            File f=new File("users//"+"user"+i.getId());
            System.out.println("Can READ: "+f.canRead());
            System.out.println("Can WRITE: "+f.canWrite());
            System.out.println("Can EXEC: "+f.canExecute());
            System.out.println("Exists: "+f.exists());
            System.out.println(f.delete());
```

Yes, I have the right to read,write,exec and the file exists. I don't have any exceptions

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are facing?

Comment: Sometimes, even though you have the right, you need to start/execute the `.jar`, or in case of development the IDE saying `Eclipse` or `Netbeans` or whatever as Administrator / in Administrator Mode

Comment: well ..it does nothing. doesn't remove the file

Comment: From http://stackoverflow.com/questions/991489/i-cant-delete-a-file-in-java you can see different solutions for this.

Comment: why are you doing this : `System.out.println(f.delete());`
Try : `f.delete();` instead

Comment: You're probably not trying to delete the file you think you're deleting. Print f.getAbsolutePath() to find out what you're trying to delete.

Comment: [Don't use File in 2015](http://java7fs.wikia.com/wiki/Why_File_sucks). Use java.nio.file.

Answer (score 3):

I have tried this code and it works:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            File file = new File("c:\\Users\\Akhil\\logfile11052015.log");
            if (file.delete()) {
                System.out.println("Success: " + file.getName() + " is deleted!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Failed: Delete operation is failed.");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

May be you can check if you are providing correct path in your case and file exists there.

Output: `Success: logfile11052015.log is deleted!`

Answer (score -1):

I needed to call `System.gc()` after the remove.